# Who is this man whose face appears randomly?

Tags: sayonara-zetsubou-sensei

Throughout **Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei**, there's a picture (not animated) of a bald man's face that appears randomly (often as a censor). Who is he and what is his relation to the show (or their creators)? Does he randomly appear in other Studio SHAFT shows?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He is [Kosaku Maeda](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%89%8D%E7%94%B0%E5%90%9B), and his nickname  is MAEDAX, he was the voice actor for several minor parts in the show (including playing himself, credited as MAEDAX) and also worked on the manga.

[Here is his picture on Anime news network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/people.php?id=67112).

Answer (score 14):

He is the mangaka's assistant, Maeda-kun.

From the TVTropes page [Manga: Sayonara, Zetsubou-Sensei](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/SayonaraZetsubouSensei):

> Fan Disservice: Some fanservice scenes can be a little awkward when they're censored by the face of Maeda-kun, Koji Kumeta's assistant, who sometimes is even facepalming disapprovingly. Shame on you.

Comment: Found the answer in a number of blog posts on the topic. Quoted TVTropes page above. Let me see if I can find a more reliable source.